# wp_set_password() does not work!

Tags: plugins, forms, password, profiles, wp-login-form

I created a simple form for my users to can change their passwords. but there is a problem and I am confused! I tried a lot to change my password but my pass will not be changed by `wp_set_password()` and I do not know the reason really.

```
<?php /* Template Name: user-edit-password */ ?>


<?php
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$userID = $user->ID;
$has_error = false;
$has_success = false;
$message = array();

if( isset($_POST['karneta_pass_submit']) ){
    if( !isset($_POST['security']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['security'],'edit-profile-password-nonce') ){
        print('do not damage that');
    } else {

        $currentpass = sanitize_text_field($_POST['karneta_currentpass']);
        $newpass = sanitize_text_field($_POST['karneta_newpass']);
        $repeatnewpass = sanitize_text_field($_POST['karneta_repeatnewpass']);

        if( wp_check_password($currentpass, $user->data->user_pass, $UserID) ){

            if( empty($currentpass) || empty($newpass) || empty($repeatnewpass) ){

                $has_error = true;
                $message[] = "fill all the fields";

            }
            elseif( $newpass !== $repeatnewpass ){

                $has_error = true;
                $message[] = "they are not the same";

            } 
            else {

                wp_set_password($newpass,$UserID);

                $has_success = true;
                $message[] = "password changed successfully"; 

            }
        } else {
            $has_error = true;
            $message[] = "the old password is not correct";
        }

    }
}
?>

<div class="usereditprofile">
    <div class="usereditprofilediv">

        <div>
            <?php if( $has_error ){ ?>
            <div class="userprofile_message error">
                <?php foreach ($message as $item) { ?>
                <p><?php echo $item; ?></p>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if( $has_success ){ ?>
            <div class="userprofile_message success">
                <?php foreach ($message as $sitem) { ?>
                <p><?php echo $sitem; ?></p>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <form action="" method="post" class="usereditprofileform">
            <?php wp_nonce_field('edit-profile-password-nonce', 'security'); ?>

            <input type="password" placeholder="old password" value="" name="karneta_currentpass" required>
            <input type="password" placeholder="new password" value="" name="karneta_newpass" required>
            <input type="password" placeholder="repeat new password" value="" name="karneta_repeatnewpass" required>
            <input type="submit" value="change your pass" name="karneta_pass_submit">

        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved myself. Ir is because of `user ID`:

## incorrect:

wp_set_password($newpass,$UserID);

## correct:

wp_set_password($newpass, $user->ID);

Answer (score 0):

Nested if/else/elseifs are usually too complex for me to figure out.

I'd change your code to use SWITCH/CASE to determine proper input and to change the password if all is OK.

And to sanitize $_POST (and $_GET) inputs, I just put this in my functions file:

```
$_GET = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Then I don't have to remember to sanitize things elsewhere.